# Android died after update

Tags: updates

LG Stylo V2 is dead after updating. Screen reads "Your device is corrupt. It can't be trusted and may not work properly."

Comment: Does anything else happen? Are there any other logos or screens shown? Can you factory reset via recovery mode or fastboot?

Comment: Did you ever root it, and are now getting this message of consequence that the company recognizes it had been done?

Comment: I went to the Verizon store and they said they never saw anything like this. They ordered me a new phone being delivered today "Next Day" Fedex. No charge for the new phone.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the Verizon store and they said they never saw anything like this. They ordered me a new phone being delivered today "Next Day" Fedex. No charge for the new phone.